# Breaker cannot turn on with nothing connected at other end

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

After a heavy rain, I cannot turn on the breaker for my washer.

I removed connection at wall outlet, no both hot and neutral wire are open, but still can not turn on breaker. try 2 different breakers, same issue.

I measure the resistance between hot, neutral, and ground wires.

N <-> G => 0 ohm.

N <-> H => 1.3M ohm

H <-> G => 1.3M ohm.

so I don't know what is the real issue?

Comment: perhaps the real issue is that the breaker is doing its job

Comment: why was the breaker turned off?

Comment: If (a big **IF**) you are competent to safely open the breaker panel and disconnect the circuit at that end, either the breaker then operates normally (and there's something wrong with the wire, or "the wire after a heavy rain" or the breaker still does not operate normally (suspect the breaker, perhaps the rain was coincidence.)

Comment: Does this breaker have a "TEST" button on it?  If so, what kind is it (AFCI or GFCI or both)?

Comment: Can you trace the path of the wire? Is there an exterior junction box that might have been compromised by the rain?

Comment: GFCI’s will continue tripping if there happens to be moisture in the receptacles, I see this quite often in older homes that have exterior receptacles but no heavy duty or in-use covers the boxes can hold water for months in some cases.

Comment: Does "cannot turn the breaker on" meant that the breaker lever _will not move_ or does it mean that you can turn it back on but that it _trips immediately_?